# Citrix not mapping printers with Office 2010 suite

Tags: printing, citrix, microsoft-office-2010

Ran into a strange issue. User connects to Citrix via Web Interface. If the user starts up an Office 2003 app, their local printer maps and shows up just fine. If they open an Office 2010 app, there is no local printer being mapped.

Has anyone run into this before? I couldn't find any hotfix or patch that references this issue but it's completely baffling me.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Are the servers in the same farm? Which OS is installed on the servers? Did you install both Office versions on the same server? How do you map the printers(login-script, GPO, etc)? Do you map network printers or local attached printers? Is this happening to one user or all users? Is this happening with one printer or all printers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a script that restarts the Citrix print manage service every morning, that seems to have cleared up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a XenDesktop 7.5 farm. There are some hotfixes, but none of them work.  I had to write a daily 12AM script to:

1. Delete the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\ClientSideRendering\Server\PrintServerNameHere`
2. Reboot the server because a remote stop/start of the print spooler is not allowed since it is dependent on the Citrix Print Spooler

Hope this helps